# Formatting Access Chart

Tags: ms-access-2010

I wish to incorporate a barchart in my access database report as a subreport. I have the data and the chart working in a subreport. The issue i have is that I only wish to show the actual barchart with no legend or title. 
However no matter what I seem to try i still get large amounts of white space below and beside the chart where these components would normally appear. This means that the actual chart is relatively small within the space allowed for the subreport object.
How can I modify the report so that white space around the edges is removed or minimised.

Thanks

Comment: Charts without a legend (and usually a title) are next to useless in my view.  Sorry for not being able to help, on the other hand :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to belong on http://superuser.com/